# How do I get Magento2 to process my _theme.less?

Tags: magento2, less

I can't figure out how to get the LESS files in my theme to update. I've tried every different .less file the docs recommend. I've tried copying this file from samples:

https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-theme/web/css/source/_theme.less

to the same exact spot in my own theme (/app/design/frontend/Grant/knit/web/css/source). I'm running in dev mode, clearing the cache, and forcing static deploy (even though I shouldn't have to), and I can't get the changes to register.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `_extend.less` instead `_theme.less` then flush cache and use

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

You can import your less file in _extend.less like bellow

```
// Custom Less
 
@import 'theme/_custom.less';   
@import 'theme/_navigation.less'; 
@import 'theme/_theme.less';
```

**NOTE**:- Run bellow commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f  
chmod 0777 -R var/*
chmod 0777 -R pub/static/* 
chmod 0777 -R generated/*
```